# Proof that the zeroes of certain polynomials are increasing with respect to degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, polynomials, zeroes

Choose $k+1$ positive integers $d_j\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and let $d=(d_1,\ldots,d_k)$.
Consider the following polynomial equation over the **positive reals**:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac1{x^{d_j}} = x^{d_{k+1}},
\quad
x>0.
$$
My intuition and bunch of numerical experiments suggest that for any $d_j$, this has a unique positive solution, and moreover, the solutions are increasing in the degree of the polynomial (in $1/x$) on the LHS. Descartes' rule implies that there is at most one solution to this equation.

More formally, define the following polynomial (note the sum is only up to $k$):
$$
p(x) = p_d(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}x^{d_j}.
$$
Write $x_d$ for the set of positive real solutions to $p_d(1/x)=x^{d_{k+1}}$.

**Conjecture:** $x_d$ is a singleton and if $d$ and $d'$ are two sequences as above, and $\deg{p_d}>\deg p_{d'}$ then $x_d>x_{d'}$.

*Note.* It's possible that weird things happen if we let $d_{k+1}$ grow too large, so I am fine with assuming $d_{k+1}\le d_j$ for all $j\ne k+1$. In fact, I only care about cases where $d_{k+1}$ is very small. But in my simulations, this did not matter.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing (to me). Do you really want to allow $d_{k+1}$ to not be the top exponent? But then Descartes rule is consistent with two positive zeros, and also $1+x^2=x$ has no positive solutions.

Comment: I am in general quite confused by this question. Do we have two sequences $(d_1, \ldots , d_{k+1})$ and $(d_1', \ldots , d_{k+1}')$, we have that $d_{k+1} \le d_j, j \le k$ and $d_{k+1}' \le d_j', j \le k$ and we ask to compare the roots of $p_d(x) = x^{d_{k+1}}$ and $p_{d'} = x^{d_{k+1}'}$? Or something completely different.

Comment: If I understood it correctly (quite likely I didn't) then can't we add the same number $s\in \mathbb{N}$ to all $d_j$? The degree will increase but the root stays the same.

Comment: Ah ha, there was a rather embarrassing (and critical) typo in my original post: The equation in question should be $p_d(1/x)=x^{d_{k+1}}$ (note the $1/x$). Obviously, without this, what I wrote is incorrect. @ChristianRemling: With this change, hopefully it is more clear why I do not want $d_{k+1}$ to be the top exponent.

Comment: @chrisv: Thank you for the correction. Now existence of a positive solution is clear, by the mean value theorem (look at your function near zero and infinity). However, you still have the problem pointed out by Aleksei, $d$ is not the right quantity to control $x$. For example, $1/x^d = x^e$ has the minimal possible solution $x=1$, even though you can make the degrees as large as you want.

Comment: (Mods: Please delete this question.) After thinking about my problem some more, I realized I had greatly oversimplified this question. I posted a much simpler special case here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462253/zeroes-of-elementary-polynomials-without-involving-closed-form-solutions