# Zeroes of elementary polynomials without involving closed-form solutions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, zeroes

Consider the following two polynomials, where $n$ is an integer:
$$
p_n(x) = x^3-\frac1nx-\frac2n, \\
q_n(x) = x^2-\frac2n.
$$
For any $n$, let $x_p=x_p(n)$ and $x_q=x_q(n)$ be the unique positive real numbers such that $p_n(x_p)=0$ and $q_n(x_q)=0$, respectively. These zeroes have closed-form expressions, and from these expressions, it is possible to verify that $x_p(n)>x_q(n)$ for all $n\ge1$.

**My question:** Is there an alternative way to prove this, without invoking either of these closed-form expressions? I confess that I am not an expert (or even a novice) on polynomials, algebra, etc.

(This pair of polynomial equations is the simplest in a sequence of [higher and higher degree] polynomials for which I conjecture a similar property holds. In trying to prove the general case, I realized I cannot even prove the simplest case without resorting to explicit solutions!)

Comment: One method is to note that $p_n(x)$ is negative on $(0,x_p(n))$ and positive on $(x_p(n),\infty)$, so it suffices to show that $p_n(x_q(n)) < 0$. But $x_q(n)^2 = 2/n$ so $p_n(x_q(n))$ simplifies to $x/n-2/n$, which is negative as $x<2$. The method here is secretly to use long division of polynomials, since the two polynomials look somewhat similar.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn "The method here is secretly to use long division of polynomials" -- in fact, you can make it explicit with a Sturm-like algorithm! I learned it from the paper of Khovanskii and Burda "Degree of rational mappings, and the theorems of Sturm and Tarski", it is applicable for pretty much any pair of polynomials and more.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first iterate of a Newton-like method for $p_n(x)$ with $x_0= \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$ (the root of $q_n(x)$).  This provides an explicit expression for $x_1$ (the first *approximate* solution of $p_n(x)$).

For simplicity, let $t= \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$ and use a Newton-like method of order $k$.

For $k>2$, the general result write

$$x_1^{(k)}=t+(2-t)\, t\,\frac{P_k(t) }{Q_k(t) }$$ where $P_k(t)$ and $Q_k(t)$ are polynomials (degree of $Q_k(t)$ being the degree of $P_k(t)$ plus $1$).  In these polynomials, all coefficients are positive.

The exact solution being
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\, t\, \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{6}}{t}\right)\right)$$ consider the norm
$$\Phi_k=\int_0^1 \Big(x-x_1^{(k)}\Big)^2\,dt$$
The results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \log_{10}(\Phi_k) \\
 3 & -3.037 \\
 4 & -4.477 \\
 5 & -4.214 \\
 6 & -4.856 \\
 7 & -5.681 \\
 8 & -5.599 \\
 9 & -6.013 \\
 10 & -6.589 \\
 11 & -6.539 \\
 12 & -6.852 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

By increasing degrees, the coefficients of $P_{12}$ are

$$\{65536,2010624,11743680,21722240,15226400,4156972,367423\}$$
and the coefficients of $Q_{12}$ are
$$\{24576,2253824,27070464,94284480,124466560,69031272,15966768,1254463\}$$

Now, the accuracy
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 1.52137971 &  1.52137971 \\
 2 & 1.16537304 &  1.16537304 \\
 3 & 1.00000000 &  1.00000000 \\
 4 & 0.89816095 &  0.89816095 \\
 5 & 0.82688697 &  0.82688697 \\
 6 & 0.77317017 &  0.77317017 \\
 7 & 0.73067452 &  0.73067453 \\
 8 & 0.69588439 &  0.69588439 \\
 9 & 0.66666667 &  0.66666667 \\
 10 & 0.64163965 &  0.64163965 \\
 20 & 0.50000019 &  0.50000000 \\
 30 & 0.43284437 &  0.43284358 \\
 40 & 0.39099845 &  0.39099661 \\
 50 & 0.36147202 &  0.36146873 \\
 60 & 0.33908159 &  0.33907653 \\
 70 & 0.32128150 &  0.32127442 \\
 80 & 0.30665013 &  0.30664084 \\
 90 & 0.29432034 &  0.29430871 \\
 100 & 0.28372793 &  0.28371387 \\
 200 & 0.22321463 &  0.22317624 \\
 300 & 0.19416582 &  0.19410899 \\
 400 & 0.17593783 &  0.17586968 \\
 500 & 0.16301227 &  0.16293889 \\
 600 & 0.15317216 &  0.15309848 \\
 700 & 0.14532363 &  0.14525359 \\
 800 & 0.13885367 &  0.13879040 \\
 900 & 0.13338732 &  0.13333333 \\
 1000 & 0.12868007 &  0.12863739 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

There is no problem going to higher orders if you wish.

You can use the same approach for the general case you mention : start from the root of $q_n(x)$ and generate the approximate root of  $p_n(x)$ with the same procedure.